# Problems when registering emojis in MySQL with ASP Classic

Tags: mysql, utf-8, asp-classic, collation

Good Morning!

I've been trying to implement emojis in my applications for a while, but I'm having a lot of difficulties. I have already tested several internet solutions, but none has been effective.

I will try to detail as much as I am doing:

- I'm using **Classic ASP** and **MySQL** in versions
  **5.6.40-84.0-log** and **5.6.26-log**.
- The application is hosted on a Plesk Windows (I tried to run locally
  and the same goes for the database). Notepad ++ pages have already
  been tested in `UTF-8` and `UTF8 without BOM`.
- In the HTML `<head>` there is `<meta charset = "utf-8">`.
- The `<form>` has the tag `accept-charset="UTF-8"`.
- The ASP has `Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"`, `Response.CodePage=65001`,`Response.LCID=1060` and `Response.Charset="utf-8"`.

Now for the problems:

In both versions of MySQL, when I change `COLLATE` to `utf8mb4_unicode_*` or `utf8mb4_bin`, it returns to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` automatically.

In version **5.6.40-84.0-log**, if I register the emojis directly in the database, they are like `??????????????`.

In version **5.6.26-log**, if I register directly with the database, the error returns:

`` Executing:
INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (` emoji`) VALUES ('tion 123  ão');
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect string value: '\ xF0 \ x9F \ x98 \ x80 \ xF0 \ x9F ...' for column 'emoji' at row 1
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO 'db'. 'Table' ('emoji') VALUES ('tion 123  ão') ``

In this same version, registering through the  of the page, using `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` or `SET NAMES' utf8'` in the **ODBC** connection string, the following error is returned:

`Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
[MySQL] [ODBC 3.51 Driver] [mysqld-5.6.22] Incorrect string value: '\ xE7 \ xE3o' for column 'field' at row 1`

**EDIT 1:**
When I consult `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';` and `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE "%collation%";` the database it returns the following results:

[image]

Thanks!

***Translation by Google Translate (rsrs)***

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

For Emoji and some Chinese, you need `utf8mb4`, not  `utf8` in MySQL.

Since you are running the old 5.6, you may stumble over another problem.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

If that E7E3 should have been `çã`, then you have some latin1-encoded text, too.

Do *not* mix encodings in a single column.

Your output for `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` shows that the *connection* is just utf8; it needs to be utf8mb4.  The main difference between them is in Emoji.

Comment: This is strange, because the error is also shown when I insert it directly into the bank, but only when there is an emoji with it. And the database is in UTF8MB4

Comment: The database does not matter; what matters is the column.

Comment: Change the connection parameters.  Use `SET NAMES utf8mb4` if you can't find what is going wrong in the parameters.

Comment: As mentioned at the beginning, if you do this, you get the error: `[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.40-log]Incorrect string value: '\xE7\xE3o' for column...`